# Add to existing Promises.all array from catch of Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having a piece of code where I am adding a few Async operations to a promise array and calling Promise.all to resolve all of them and await the result.
I have an expectation to check for failure of second operation and perform operation one from its catch block if it so happens.
If I am attaching a catch block to one of the promises of this array and performing an async operation can I add to the same promise array or am I better off to await this operation separately.

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(performAsync1(record))
promises.push(performAsync2().catch(() =>
   console.error("Async2 Failed");
   promises.push(performAsync1(failedRecord));
}
const responses = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: How would you use `responses` then? Why not just use a promise chain `promises.push(performAsync2().catch(() => performAsync1()))`

Comment: "*can I add to the same promise array*" - no. It won't be picked up by the `Promise.all` if you're adding it asynchronously *after* the `Promise.all()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may get closed for being "primarily" opinion based, but I would assign that  performAsync2 operation/retry combo to a variable.

```
const performAsync2Retrying = performAsync2(record).catch(()=> performAsync1(record))
const promises = []
promises.push(performAsync1(record))
promises.push(performAsync2Retrying)
const responses = await Promise.all(promises)
```

This makes the construction of your promises array easy to read with a single responsibility.

Writing this in a more modern idiom makes the goodnes even clearer:

```
const performAsync2Retrying = performAsync2(record).catch(()=> performAsync1(record))
const responses = await Promise.all([performAsync1(record),
    performAsync2Retrying])
```

But what I'd really want to do here is to avoid introducing the extra name  with a helper function that executes a second function if the first fails (which could be elaborated on to handle multiple arguments)

```
const retryWith = (f1, f2, _in) => f1(_in).catch(_=>f2(_in))

const responses = await Promise.all([
    performAsync1(record),
    retryWith(performAsync2, performAsync1, record)
 ])
```

And then I never need to think about handling this scenario again.

Comment: Why would you introduce an extra helper function that's called only once? I don't see how that improves clarity.

Comment: I find it easier to read. Leaving it as it was is an invitation to others to add more such complex constructions into the promise array.  One might want to create a generic helper function if this something you do all the time. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: I'd think there's nothing wrong with storing the promise in a temporary variable, but why use a function for that? (Of course, to increase readability you'd also build the array as a single literal with two elements instead of using `push`).

Comment: exactly how I ended the post.  Putting that catch construction into the literal would be awful.  You are right assigning the promise to a variable would be better than what I did.  

Best of all would be a function like retryWith(f1, f2), but that's also a matter of taste.